# C# https request always tunnel to server but Java only once

Tags: c#, java, http, network-programming

I'm converting JAVA program to C# that send `https` request to server. Here is my program that log in to server and then log-out from server.

```
  var login_httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_base_url + "session/login");
  login_httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

  var logout_httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_base_url + "session/logout");
  logout_httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

  CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
  login_httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;


  using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(login_httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
  {
      streamWriter.Write("{username:xxxxxx,password:yyyyyyy}");
  }
  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)login_httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
  var login_cookies = httpResponse.Cookies;

  logout_httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(login_cookies);
  using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(logout_httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
  {
      streamWriter.Write("{}");
  }

  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)login_httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

But my C# program takes more time than the original JAVA program and then I checked the request using Fiddler tool. So I found for every request C# Tunnel to server. but JAVA program only once.

Bellow image

- Green color shows requests (tunnel->login->logout) sent to server by JAVA program.
- Red color shows C# program requests(tunnel->login->tunnel->logout) sent to server by C# program.

[image]

Anyone knows how to avoid tunneling for each request by C# Http client.

Comment: Check [KeepAlive property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), should be `true` by default, but maybe your actual code resets it...

Comment: Every request has `Connection: Keep-Alive` header. and the both requests send by JAVA program and  C# is Identical. I guess issue is in C# code. there should be a ways the use the same session.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Check on sniffer if java is using http1.0 or http1.1.  Also check if java is GZIP.  Why is c# login each time?  Is the connection closing?  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  The TCP may show a [FIN] which is an indciation the connection closed.  You can also use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to verify the status of the connection to see if it closed.

Comment: My guess is that each instance of WebRequest is creating it's own connection.   I don't really see a method to cause it to re-use the connection.  Typically I use HttpClient instead and create only one instance per base url.   See https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ for more infor on this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using HttpClient instead of WebRequest?  I wrote this up with no way to test it so hopefully it's close....

```
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, m_base_url + "session/login");
            requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{username:xxxxxx,password:yyyyyyy}"); ;

            HttpResponseMessage loginResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

            // The HttpClient should already have the cookies from the login so
            // no need to transfer
            requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, m_base_url + "session/logout");
            requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{}");

            HttpResponseMessage logoutResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's it my dude! Thanks for the solution. The solution is: use HttpClient isntead of raw HttpRequestMessage.